# Copy files from cd to hard disk

Tags: windows-10

I'm new to windows 10. I find that I can no longer copy a simple file, a song, from a CD to hard disk, remove the CD, and then play the song, because any means of copy that I try copies files as short cuts or with links. Short cuts or linked files cannot be played when the original file on the CD is removed. What do I do?

Comment: You have never been able to do this in windows, you need cd ripping software, [I use CDEX for this](http://cdex.mu/)

Answer (score 0):

**Copying files from CD to HDD :**

Open cmd prompt. Switch to the cd drive by typing `E:`(which evr drive letter it is on). Now type: `copy *.* <location>`(fill in wherever you want it copied to). Once its done `exit` cmd prompt. Done.

Note: If you are trying to copy an **Audio Disc** (which is not a disc with mp3 songs in them), then you will have to **use a ripping software**(Even Windows Media player has a rip option, maybe use that).